# get input alert onBackPressed Android

Tags: android

I am trying to get an input from custom dialog when the user clicks back from the activity.
I override the `onBackPressed()` method, I see the dialog but the activity closed right after it.

I also tried to move the `super.onBackPressed();` to after calling the dialog

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(enableTimer) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
    if(enableHistorySaving){
        showCustomDialog(vp.getCurrentItem());
        // i want the activity will be closed here after  getting input.
    }
}
```

showCustomDialogMethod:

```
public void showCustomDialog(final int position){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ExerciseActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.enter_data);
    dialog.setTitle("save your data...");

    Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int numOfSets = Integer.valueOf(((EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.numOfSetsDialog)).getText().toString());
            final String wights = ((EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.wights)).getText().toString();
            saveToExcelFile(dayExercises.get(position),wights,numOfSets);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    Button cencelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cencel);
    cencelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Your users will hate it. Just autosave when the user leaves. And if your intent is to save when the user leaves your app, "on back" isn't going to catch cases where the user presses home or another activity is raised on top of yours, or the user taps on a notification with an action.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are showing a dialog to save user data before exiting.

Add this line `super.onBackPressed();` in `setOnClickListener` methods of the dialog buttons

**Note:** It must be the last line in the listener method

Comment: Did you add it after `dialog.dismiss();` line in the `onClick()` of dialog buttons?

Comment: no. now it works. but i should add finish() instead super. because i couldn't call super from this inner class. tnx

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Happy coding.!

Answer (score 0):

you can use fragment to show alert with this code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    doubleBackToExitPressed(R.id.content_dashboard);
}

public void doubleBackToExitPressed(int content) {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .remove(manager.findFragmentById(content))
                    .commit();
            manager.popBackStack();
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(content, Question.newInstance()
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    }
```

main_activity.xml :

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

question.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/question_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="question"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:weightSum="100">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@color/colorGrayLight"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_title_dialog"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
                android:layout_weight="32"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/is_login_or"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="40"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:weightSum="100">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_cancel_question_answer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="40"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/no"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_ok_question_answer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="40"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/yes"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="20" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="28" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="40" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

question.java :

```
public class Question extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.user_question)
    LottieAnimationView user_question;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_title_dialog)
    TextView txt_title_dialog;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_cancel_question_answer)
    TextView txt_cancel_question_answer;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_ok_question_answer)
    TextView txt_ok_question_answer;

    public static Question newInstance() {
        Question question = new Question();
        return question;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, parent, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.txt_cancel_question_answer)
    public void setTxt_cancel_question_answer() {
        removeQuestion();

// you can set action for cancel this is



    }

    @OnClick(R.id.txt_ok_question_answer)
    public void setTxt_ok_question_answer() {
        removeQuestion();
// you can set action for ok this is

    }

    public void removeQuestion() {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .remove(manager.findFragmentById(content))
                .commit();
        manager.popBackStack();
    }
}
```

I'm use butter Knife you can see website and learn !
http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Answer (score -1):

You can call finish() method. That will finish the activity on press of ok button after accepting the input from user.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
if(enableTimer)  
{
    countDownTimer.cancel();
}
if(enableHistorySaving)
{
    showCustomDialog(vp.getCurrentItem());

}
}

public void showCustomDialog(final int position){
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ExerciseActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.enter_data);
dialog.setTitle("save your data...");

Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int numOfSets = Integer.valueOf(((EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.numOfSetsDialog)).getText().toString());
        final String wights = ((EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.wights)).getText().toString();
        saveToExcelFile(dayExercises.get(position),wights,numOfSets);
        dialog.dismiss();
        finish();
    }
});
Button cencelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cencel);
cencelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

}

This is updated answer. Please have a look @keiloda

Comment: This will not work, super.onBackPressed(); will close the activity